# Where do you sleep while on tour?

Tags: touring

Where do you stay when you are on tour?  Hotels?  Campsites? [Stealth Camping](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/261/stealth-camping)?

Comment: I vote to close; too subjective, and can lead to arguments about stealth camping. Also, see [this thread in meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7/bike-touring-and-camping). Touring is in scope as long as it sticks to on-topic areas.

Comment: This is a bit off topic and too open.  Maybe restating the question would help.

Comment: If you are not interested; you should no look at things tagged touring or camping.  See my meta post: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7/bike-touring-and-camping/23#23

Comment: Whether or not this is on topic is one question (currently being discussed on meta). Another is whether this is a good question. In my opinion, this is an opinion poll, vague and broad, with multiple, "chatty" answers. I think it should be closed as subjective.

Comment: I think this question is partly misunderstood. I want to make a similar question with different slant. Do you use `hammock`, `tent` or can you something else `self-sustainable`? And, of course, it should light-weight. How can you see from a map in unknown area where should you relax? Do you check it from web or can you look for geographical things? There is a lot of legit things you must consider for sleeping, I think they are very essential for touring. Hence, I suggest to reopen or let me do a better question with the same/similar title.

Comment: @hhh, we decided in meta that questions **specifically about camping** are off-topic. Here's [the specific question where this was decided](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7/bike-touring-and-camping). May I recommend the excellent [Accommodations forums on Crazy Guy On a Bike](http://goo.gl/xsiUL)? (I spend a good amount of time there and have several journals on the site.) Alternately, feel free to contribute to the discussion on meta if you disagree with the decision; perhaps you can get the community to reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

Mixture of campsites, friends and hotels. If I've got a rest day (staying in one city and checking things out) typically hotel.

I have some friends that just went up to houses and asked if they could camp on the lawn. They rode from Toronto to PEI with no camping fees.

Comment: I get scared to ride through some places, much less ask people to camp on their lawn!  I need to move to a more bicycle-friendly area...

Comment: Yeah the maritime provinces are pretty friendly. A few times my friends saw people at a rest stop that lived locally and got invited over. In fact most times the family invited them in for diner and offered showers, drives to the grocery store...Us Canucks are a friendly bunch.